# Overwriting of Windows built-in variables

Tags: autohotkey

The `%path%` is Windows built-in environment variable. For some reason, when it used as custom output variable in AHK-code, it **sometimes** overwrited, **sometimes** - not. Why?

```
; Launch it in Windows Explorer (i.e. default file manager)

foo() {
    winGetText, path, a
    msgbox %path% ; will be overwrited with window text
    return
}

bar() {
    winGetText, winText, a
    regExMatch(winText, "Address: .*[^\r\n]", path)
    msgbox %path% ; Will not be overwrited
    return
}

f1:: foo()
f2:: bar()
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as I miss understood. That is odd. But why use variable names if they are environment names as well? In other languages this is just not supported.

Comment: @ZackTarr I use this code to retrieve path of currently opened folder. And, from my point of view, it's easier and more intuitive to store path in `path` variable, instead of some "non-standard" names, like `folderPath` or `thePathOfCurrentlyOpenedFolder` - the first is ugly, the second is too wordy. I suppose, if we have predictable logic of overwriting - it's okay to overwrite. But, as I accidentally discovered and as you see now, the logic is quite *not* predictable.

Comment: I would think best practice would be to use custom names, my favorite method is just adding `My` infront for `MyPath` rather `path`.  I feel this is also better as it makes the code easier to read for others as they might not notice the overwriting of the path variable when reviewing.

Comment: @ZackTarr Also, sometimes developers adds first letters of their names to variables. For John Doe it will be "jdSomeVar". As Boiler at AHK forums suggested, the problem could be avoided if we add `#NoEnv` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no answer about "why", but the ambiguity of overwriting could be eliminated using [`#noEnv`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_NoEnv.htm) and [`envGet`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvGet.htm):

```
#noEnv

foo() {
    winGetText, path, a
    msgBox, %path% ; Will be overwrited with window text
    return
}

bar() {
    winGetText, winText, a
    regExMatch(winText, "Address: .*[^\r\n]", path)
    msgBox, %path% ; Will be overwrited with window text
    return
}

baz() {
    ; Nothing will be here, since we disabled environment variables:
    msgBox, %path%
    ; So, if we need some environment variable, we need to invoke it:
    envGet, a_path, path
    msgBox, %a_path%
    return
}

f1:: foo()
f2:: bar()
f3:: baz()
```

[The main point of this answer was suggested by Boiler at AHK forums.](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=44509)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is how it is suppose to be designed or not but it looks like there is a recommendation on how to retrieve env variables. [AHK Wiki EnvGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Concepts.htm#environment-variables)

Based on the documentation the fix will be to only pull data from environment variables with the `EnvGet, OutputVar, Path` method.

The fix:

```
foo() {
    winGetText, path, a
    EnvGet, OutputVar, path
    msgbox %OutputVar% 
    return
}
f1:: foo()
```

Comment: Yes, I know. My question isn't about **getting** environment variables. It's about use of my custom vars, which sometimes conflicts with env. vars. So, your answer isn't related to it. (But I will not downvote).